# Can SQLite DB files be made read-only?

Tags: perl, sqlite, file-permissions, readonly

Information from an SQLite DB is presented to user through a web server (displayed in an HTML browser). The DB is loaded once for all by a small application independent from the web server. DB data cannot be changed from user browser (this is a read-only service).

As the web-server has its own user-id, it accesses the SQLite DB file with "other" permissions. For security reason, I would like to set the DB file permissions as `rw-rw-r--`.

Unfortunately, with this permission set, I get a warning `attempt to write a readonly database at line xxx` which points to a line about a `SELECT` transaction (which in principle is read-only). Of course, I get no result.

If permissions are changed to `rw-rw-rw`, everything works fine, but that means everybody can tamper with the DB.

**Is there any reason why SQLite DB cannot be accessed read-only?**

**Are there "behind-the-scene" processings which need write access, even for SELECT transactions?**

*Look-up on StackOverflow shows that people usually complain for the opposite situation: encountering a read-only access permission preventing writing to the DB. My goal is to protect my DB against ANY change attempt.*

For the complete story, my web app is written in `Perl` and uses `DBD::SQLite`

Comment: It looks to me like [some versions](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.48/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm) of DBD::SQLite allow you to specify [standard SQLite URI parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html).  One of those is `mode=ro`.

Comment: Are you using WAL mode?

Comment: @CL DB is opened with default modes; WAL mode is enabled only if it is default

Comment: I can make my SQLite database read-only and still access it and execute SELECT statements with DBD::SQLite, so this appears to be platform- or version-specific.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: I converted to URI parameters but it does not work

Comment: @reinierpost How's your DB readonly? File permissions with or w/o mode parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is given in the answer to this question [Perl DBI treats setting SQLite DB cache_size as a write operation when subclassing DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793672/perl-dbi-treats-setting-sqlite-db-cache-size-as-a-write-operation-when-subclassi).

It turns out that `AutoCommit` cannot be set to 0 with read-only SQLite DB. Explicitly forcing it to 1 in the read-only DB case solved the problem.

Thanks to all who gave clues and leads.

Comment: I would consider accepting your own answer appropriate. It probably does not affect your rep, but it labels the answer as "this helped me", which I think is a useful info for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You must connect to your SQLite db in `readonly` mode.

From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#Database-Name-Is-A-File-Name):

> You can also set sqlite_open_flags (only) when you connect to a database:
>
> ```
> use DBD::SQLite;
> my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", undef, undef, {
>   sqlite_open_flags => DBD::SQLite::OPEN_READONLY,
> });
> ```

-- https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#Database-Name-Is-A-File-Name

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I believe it does. The idea is that the file can be made readonly if you connect to it this way.

Comment: It does if that is true.

Comment: @Asaph: No success with sqlite_open_flags as with URI parameter